# properties of the Frattini subgroup of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, frattini-subgroup

I am reading the following proposition
[image]

the question is: where do we use the hypothesis that $G$ is a finite group in the first point?

Comment: An infinite group might not have maximal subgroups.

Comment: @the_fox In that case, Frat $G$ = $G$. I think (i) probably holds for infinite groups.

Comment: @Derek Holt. Ok, I thougth maybe using the modular law, but holds also for infinite groups. So in wich point do we use the hypotesis?